# Print out the date after a number of days from June 1st,2013

Tags: java, days, ready

how would i make a program that prints out the date after a number of days from June 1st,2013?
Any help is appreciated

Example: if 45 is entered it should output July 16,2013

Im using ReadyToPrgram btw if this matters

Comment: You can do this entirely with JDK classes.  Have a look at the `Calendar` class and the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/)  is one nice tutorial

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd"); 

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013,7,1);    
System.out.println("Date : " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

//add one month
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("Date : " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid comment but im new and how do i get SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @user3183193 You can use your IDE to assist you with the necessary imports. Use Eclipse or Netbeans to import. java.text is the package you need to import for SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

This will increase any date by exactly one

```
String untildate="2013-07-16";//can take any date in current format    
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );   
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
cal.setTime( dateFormat.parse(untildate));    
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );    
String convertedDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());    
System.out.println("Date increase by one.."+convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes bundled with Java. But they are notoriously troublesome.

## Joda-Time

For years now the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) third-party open-source library has been a popular substitute.

If you are sure you want just the date alone, without time and time zones use Joda-Time’s [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class. Example…

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2013, 6, 1 ).plusDays( 45 );
System.out.println( "localDate " + localDate );
```

## Search StackOverflow

Search around StackOverflow.com. These basic date and time questions have already been asked and answered.